# Operaciones de conjuntos en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, conjuntos

Sean los conjuntos **A** y **B**. Estaba haciendo un programa donde se requerían operaciones de unión y probé las siguientes:

```
 A |= B
 A.union(B)
 A = A | B
```

La única que me dio resultado para que **A** fuera la unión iterando dentro de un bucle **for** fue la última opción.

¿No se supone que estas funciones hacen un poco lo mismo o hay alguna diferencia sutil que se me escapa?

Las dos primeras lo que hacían era asignar el valor de **B** a **A**. Finalmente otra que funciona es:

```
A = A.union(B)
```

Yo **suponía sin embargo que no eran necesarios los operadores de asignación** para que hiciera la unión y la asignara a **A** ¿Estoy equivocado?

**Edición**

El código que tengo escrito es el siguiente:

```
numero_estudiantes = int(input())
for i in range(numero_estudiantes):
    print(i)
    numero_idiomas = int(input())
    idiomas_estudiante = set()
    for j in range(numero_idiomas):
        idiomas_estudiante.add(input())
    if i == 0:
        inter_idiomas = idiomas_estudiante
        uni_idiomas = idiomas_estudiante
    print(idiomas_estudiante)
    inter_idiomas &= idiomas_estudiante

    uni_idiomas |= idiomas_estudiante #Esta línea es la problemática.

    print(idiomas_estudiante)
    print(uni_idiomas)
print('\n\n\n', len(inter_idiomas))
print(*sorted(list(inter_idiomas)), sep = '\n')
print(len(uni_idiomas))
print(*sorted(list(uni_idiomas)), sep = '\n')
```

La entrada para el programa es esta:

```
3
3
Russian
English
Japanese
2
Russian
English
1
English
```

Se supone que la salida final(excepto los `print()` que he dejado internamente del bucle **for** para hacer pruebas y ver como se comportaban las variables pero que se pueden eliminar o dejar como comentarios si se quiere) ha de ser esta:

```
 1
English
3
English
Japanese
Russian
```

Eso obtengo cuando cambio la línea problemática por la línea `uni_idiomas = uni_idiomas | idiomas_estudiante`. Pero si lo hago con la  línea que he dejado en el código o sea `uni_idiomas |= idiomas_estudiante`, obtengo esto:

```
 1
English
1
English
```

La versión es **Python 3.8.5.** Lo he probado en algunos interpretadores online(por ejemplo en el de **hackerrank**) y me pasa lo mismo.

También he usado la línea `uni_idiomas.update(idiomas_estudiante)` que lo que yo entiendo que hace es actualizar la unión a la variable `uni_idiomas` pero el resultado es:

```
 1
English
1
English
```

que también la probé en el interpretador de mi PC como en hackerrank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Las expresiones siguientes *deberían* ser equivalentes:

```
uni_idiomas |= idiomas_estudiante 
uni_idiomas = uni_idiomas | idiomas_estudiante
```

Sin embargo en el código que has puesto de ejemplo, *efectivamente*, producen diferente resultado. Esto es un pequeño enigma que vamos a resolver.

### ¿Son realmente equivalentes?

No del todo. La operación `A |= B` modifica **directamente** el conjunto `A`, sin crear ningún otro conjunto intermedio para la operación.

En cambio la operación `A = A|B` en realidad hace dos cosas:

1. Toma lo que hay en `A` y calcula la unión con `B`. Eso crea un nuevo conjunto con el resultado, sin modificar ni `A` ni `B`
2. Asigna la referencia `A` para que "apunte" al nuevo resultado. El conjunto al que originalmente apuntaba `A` se queda "sin referencias" y es eliminado de memoria por Python.

Dicho de otra forma, usando `A |= B` la referencia `A` apunta al mismo sitio antes y después de la operación, pero los contenidos de ese sitio han cambiado. Por el contrario usando `A = A|B` la referencia `A` cambia y no es la misma antes y después de la operación. Antes apuntaba a un conjunto y después apuntará a otro (con el resultado).

Esto puede tener su importancia y de hecho es la razón del comportamiento observado.

### La explicación al misterio.

Unas líneas antes de esta que nos ocupa aparecen estas otras:

```
    if i == 0:
        inter_idiomas = idiomas_estudiante
        uni_idiomas = idiomas_estudiante
```

Es decir, en la primera iteración del bucle se crean las referencias `inter_idiomas` y `uni_idiomas`, ambas "apuntando" al mismo conjunto, que es `idiomas_estudiante`. Es decir, estas tres variables (`idiomas_estudiante`, `inter_idiomas` y `uni_idiomas`) son en realidad **el mismo conjunto**, bajo tres referencias o nombres diferentes.

Veamos qué ocurre entonces con tus datos de entrada.

1. Primera iteración del bucle, las tres variables toman el mismo valor `{'Japanese', 'Russian', 'English'}`y se refieren al mismo conjunto en realidad a través de las tres variables.
2. Segunda iteración del bucle. La variable `idiomas_estudiante` es un conjunto nuevo que contiene `{'Russian', 'English'}`. La variable `inter_idiomas` se actualiza *in situ* y pasa a valer `{'Russian', 'English'}`. Y ya que `uni_idiomas` es en realidad una referencia al mismo conjunto, también pasa a valer `{'Russian', 'English'}` como consecuencia de la modificación de `inter_idiomas`. Cuando luego haces `uni_idiomas |= idiomas_estudiante` no es de extrañar que queden sólo esos dos idiomas.
3. En la tercera iteracion, `idiomas_estudiante` es un nuevo conjunto que contiene `{'English'}`. La variable `inter_idiomas` que valía `{'Russian', 'English'}` se actualiza *in situ* y pasa a valer `{'English'}`. La variable `uni_idiomas` también cambia de valor en ese momento por ser una referencia al mismo conjunto  referenciado por `inter_idiomas`. Así que vale `{'English'}`, por lo que al hacerle `uni_idiomas |= idiomas_estudiante` no cambia.

De ese modo al final `uni_idiomas` contiene `{'English'}` (lo mismo que `inter_idiomas` ya que, lo repito una vez más, **son el mismo conjunto**).

Todo esto viene de la inicialización de `inter_idiomas` y de `uni_idiomas`, ambos como referencias al mismo objeto, y de la posterior actualización *in situ* de esos objetos.

Este extraño efecto desaparece al reemplazar `uni_idiomas |= idiomas_estudiante`   por `uni_idiomas = uni_idiomas | idiomas_estudiante` debido a que en este segundo objeto no se modifica *in situ*, sino que se crea un nuevo conjunto y se "rompe" así la identidad de las referencias, que ya no se referirán al mismo conjunto.

### Solución

Aparte de cambiar las asignaciones `&=` y `|=`, cosa que funcionaría debido a lo antes explicado, también podrías haber cambiado las asignaciones iniciales así:

```
    if i == 0:
        inter_idiomas = set(idiomas_estudiante)
        uni_idiomas = set(idiomas_estudiante)
```

Al añadir `set()` de este modo estamos creando conjuntos nuevos (con los mismos elementos, sí, pero son objetos diferentes). De este modo `inter_idiomas` y `uni_idiomas` se refieren ya a objetos distintos de modo que actualizar *in situ* cada uno de ellos no afecta al otro.

Así podrás seguir usando `&=` y `|=` y obtener el resultado esperado.

Comment: Pues perfectamente explicado. Muchas gracias, esto me va a evitar bastantes dolores de cabeza con todos los operadores de asignación en el futuro.